# How to pull XML key "value" from SQL CLOB

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xml-parsing, clob

I am attempting to extract information from XML stored in a CLOB column. I've searched the forums and thus far have been unable to get the data to pull as needed. I have a basic understanding of SQL but this is beyond me.

The XML is similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Response>
    <Header>
        <OrderNum value="12354321"/>
        <ExtractDate value="11-30-2012"/>
        <RType value="Status"/>
        <Company value="Company"/>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Status>
            <Order>
                <ActivityType value="ValidateRequest"/>
                <EndUser>
                    <Name value="Schmo, Joe"/>
                    <Address>
                        <SANO value="12345"/>
                        <SASN value="Mickey Mouse"/>
                        <SATH value="Lane"/>
                        <SASS value="N"/>
                        <City value="Orlando"/>
                        <State value="FL"/>
                        <Zip value="34786"/>
                        <Number value="5550000"/>
                    </Address>
                </EndUser>
                <COS value="1"/>
                <TOS value="3"/>
                <MainNumber value="5550000"/>
            </Order>
            <ErrorCode value="400"/>
            <ErrorMessage value="RECEIVED"/>
        </Status>
    </Body>
</Response>
```

I want to get the values under "Address".

I've tried the following but it returns "NULL".

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(RESPONSE_CLOB),'/Response/Body/Status/Order/EndUser/Address/SANO') AS SANO
FROM RESPONSE_TABLE
WHERE ROWNUM < 2
```

I am trying to get it so I can pull the "12345" assigned as "value" in "SANO" (ultimately getting the value for other fields, but want to at least get the one working first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently retrieving the text value of the node, but 12345 is the value attribute of the element rather than its text content. So you would need to use the `@attribute` syntax, i.e.:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(RESPONSE_CLOB),'/Response/Body/Status/Order/EndUser/Address/SANO/@value') AS SANO
FROM RESPONSE_TABLE
WHERE ROWNUM < 2;

SANO                
--------------------
12345
```

But [`extractvalue` is deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions069.htm#SQLRF06173); assuming you're on a recent version of Oracle it would be better to use an [XMLQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions265.htm):

```
SELECT XMLQUERY(
  '/Response/Body/Status/Order/EndUser/Address/SANO/@value'
  PASSING XMLTYPE(RESPONSE_CLOB)
  RETURNING CONTENT
  ) AS SANO
FROM RESPONSE_TABLE
WHERE ROWNUM < 2;
```

You may find it even easier to use an [XMLTable](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions269.htm) - necessary if an XML document has multiple `Address` nodes, but even with just one pulling the values out as columns is less repetitive, and it makes it easier to retrieve suitable  data types:

```
select x.*
from response_table rt
cross join xmltable(
  '/Response/Body/Status/Order/EndUser/Address'
  passing xmltype(rt.response_clob)
  columns sano number path 'SANO/@value',
    sasn varchar2(30) path 'SASN/@value',
    sath varchar2(10) path 'SATH/@value'
    -- etc.
) x
where rownum < 2;

                SANO SASN                           SATH      
-------------------- ------------------------------ ----------
               12345 Mickey Mouse                   Lane
```

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb04cre.htm) about using these functions to query XML data.

Comment: All three examples work great! And, yes, the third using the XMLTABLE is going to be the easiest. Thank you so much!